# prevent duplicate value to submit using stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server

> I want to prevent the same @coupon_value in sp to submit and return
> any message for validation using csharp but I am not able to how to
> make changes in stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[USP_REBATE_CAMPAIGN_RULE_DETAIL_VALIDATE]   
@rebate_campaign_seq INT,  
@coupon_value Varchar(50)='',  
@Type varchar(50)='SERIES'  
AS    
SET NOCOUNT ON    
BEGIN  
SELECT rcrd.rebate_campaign_rule_detail_seq  AS id,Type_value      AS NAME,   
       'SERIES'                    AS type,   
       rcrd.amount_per_range       AS Amount   
FROM   rebate_campaign_rule_detail rcrd (nolock)   
       INNER JOIN rebate_campaign_rule rcr   
               ON rcr.rebate_campaign_rule_seq = rcrd.rebate_campaign_rule_seq   
       INNER JOIN rebate_campaign rc   
               ON rc.rebate_campaign_seq = rcr.rebate_campaign_seq   
WHERE  rc.rebate_campaign_seq = @rebate_campaign_seq   
       AND rcrd.active_flag = 'Y' AND rcrd.type = @Type  
    AND rcrd.type_value=@coupon_value  
End
```

Comment: Note - `nolock` is not helping data integrity here.

Comment: Using obsolete and deprecated hint syntax is also not helping. [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) is not a magic, consequence-free feature nor a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent duplicate in database data is to add a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT. Everything else will fail, especially any solution coded with a procedural program, because of concurrency (imagine for a moment that two users launch the same procedure with the same values at the same time...).

To have a NULLbale UNIQUE constraint, you can add a UNIQUE filtered INDEX like this one :

```
CREATE INDEX X_UNIQUE_COUPON_RCRD 
   ON rebate_campaign_rule_detail (type_value)
   WHERE type_value IS NOT NULL;
```